# Does strace print argument values before or after the system call?

Tags: strace

When a system call modifies its arguments, does strace print the modified values, or the original values that were passed in?

For example, here is some strace output for the epoll_wait system call:

`11:30:14.602559 epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT, {u32=1210872224, u64=140506770993568}}, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT, {u32=1208190976, u64=140506768312320}}}, 128, 0) = 2`

The second argument to epoll_wait is filled in by the system call. Since there are two events in the structure, and the return value is 2, I am guessing that strace prints the values AFTER the call has completed. But I can't find any documentation that verifies this.

Answer (score 0):

It varies between system calls. In the particular case of `epoll`, this is printed here:

https://github.com/adetaylor/strace-android/blob/android/desc.c#L731

(apologies that's a rather strange branch, but the principle still applies).

The code is:

```
static void
epoll_wait_common(struct tcb *tcp)
{
if (entering(tcp)) {
    printfd(tcp, tcp->u_arg[0]);
    tprints(", ");
} else {
    if (syserror(tcp))
        tprintf("%lx", tcp->u_arg[1]);
    else if (tcp->u_rval == 0)
        tprints("{}");
    else {
...
```

The `if (entering(tcp))` bit answers your question - this code is called twice. The first time, that `if` is triggered and it will just print the file descriptor and a comma. The second time it enters the `else` section and prints the rest of the details.